# Center a drop-down select scroll bar to the selected item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop-down selector with a large amount of items. I want to center scroll the box when it gets opened to have the selected item centered in the middle of it.

Here's a picture to show what I want, except I'm looking to do this in a drop-down list selector.

[image: example]

Here's an example of the dropdown I'm using:

```html
<select name="EndTime" id="endTime">
  <option value="00:00">12:00am</option>
  <option value="00:15">12:15am</option>
  <option value="00:30">12:30am</option>
  <option value="00:45">12:45am</option>
  <option value="01:00">1:00am</option>
  <option value="01:15">1:15am</option>
  <option value="01:30">1:30am</option>
  <option value="01:45">1:45am</option>
  <option value="02:00">2:00am</option>
  <option value="02:15">2:15am</option>
  <option value="02:30">2:30am</option>
  <option value="02:45">2:45am</option>
  <option value="03:00">3:00am</option>
  <option value="03:15">3:15am</option>
  <option value="03:30">3:30am</option>
  <option value="03:45">3:45am</option>
  <option value="04:00">4:00am</option>
  <option value="04:15">4:15am</option>
  <option value="04:30">4:30am</option>
  <option value="04:45">4:45am</option>
  <option value="05:00">5:00am</option>
  <option value="05:15">5:15am</option>
  <option value="05:30">5:30am</option>
  <option value="05:45">5:45am</option>
  <option value="06:00">6:00am</option>
  <option value="06:15">6:15am</option>
  <option value="06:30">6:30am</option>
  <option value="06:45">6:45am</option>
  <option value="07:00">7:00am</option>
  <option value="07:15">7:15am</option>
  <option value="07:30">7:30am</option>
  <option value="07:45">7:45am</option>
  <option value="08:00">8:00am</option>
  <option value="08:15">8:15am</option>
  <option value="08:30">8:30am</option>
  <option value="08:45">8:45am</option>
  <option value="09:00">9:00am</option>
  <option value="09:15">9:15am</option>
  <option value="09:30">9:30am</option>
  <option value="09:45">9:45am</option>
  <option value="10:00">10:00am</option>
  <option value="10:15">10:15am</option>
  <option value="10:30">10:30am</option>
  <option value="10:45">10:45am</option>
  <option value="11:00">11:00am</option>
  <option value="11:15">11:15am</option>
  <option value="11:30">11:30am</option>
  <option value="11:45">11:45am</option>
  <option value="12:00">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="12:15">12:15pm</option>
  <option value="12:30">12:30pm</option>
  <option value="12:45">12:45pm</option>
  <option value="13:00">1:00pm</option>
  <option value="13:15">1:15pm</option>
  <option value="13:30">1:30pm</option>
  <option value="13:45">1:45pm</option>
  <option value="14:00">2:00pm</option>
  <option value="14:15">2:15pm</option>
  <option value="14:30">2:30pm</option>
  <option value="14:45">2:45pm</option>
  <option value="15:00">3:00pm</option>
  <option value="15:15">3:15pm</option>
  <option value="15:30">3:30pm</option>
  <option value="15:45">3:45pm</option>
  <option value="16:00">4:00pm</option>
  <option value="16:15">4:15pm</option>
  <option value="16:30">4:30pm</option>
  <option value="16:45">4:45pm</option>
  <option value="17:00">5:00pm</option>
  <option value="17:15">5:15pm</option>
  <option value="17:30">5:30pm</option>
  <option value="17:45">5:45pm</option>
  <option value="18:00" selected="selected">6:00pm</option>
  <option value="18:15">6:15pm</option>
  <option value="18:30">6:30pm</option>
  <option value="18:45">6:45pm</option>
  <option value="19:00">7:00pm</option>
  <option value="19:15">7:15pm</option>
  <option value="19:30">7:30pm</option>
  <option value="19:45">7:45pm</option>
  <option value="20:00">8:00pm</option>
  <option value="20:15">8:15pm</option>
  <option value="20:30">8:30pm</option>
  <option value="20:45">8:45pm</option>
  <option value="21:00">9:00pm</option>
  <option value="21:15">9:15pm</option>
  <option value="21:30">9:30pm</option>
  <option value="21:45">9:45pm</option>
  <option value="22:00">10:00pm</option>
  <option value="22:15">10:15pm</option>
  <option value="22:30">10:30pm</option>
  <option value="22:45">10:45pm</option>
  <option value="23:00">11:00pm</option>
  <option value="23:15">11:15pm</option>
  <option value="23:30">11:30pm</option>
  <option value="23:45">11:45pm</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why do you want this?

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant current code? You might be able to do this by selecting a value 5-6 places down the list(effectively bringing your original choice to the center) and then coming back to the original value.

Comment: I'm using a drop-down to select a time of day based on a specific granularity. The items are sorted. Currently the selected item is the last one displayed when the list opens, so if the user wants to select a later time, then they have to scroll down. In terms of code, there's not much to show. It's a <select> with a ton of <option> in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, but it does work

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/3Rh4Y/4/)

```
$('#listF').click(function() {
    var n = 10;
    var val = this.selectedIndex;
    if ((this.selectedIndex < ($(this).find('option').length - n)) && (this.selectedIndex > n)) {
        this.selectedIndex += n;
        this.selectedIndex -= (2 * n);
        this.selectedIndex += n;
    } else {
        this.selectedIndex = ((this.selectedIndex<n)?0:99);
        this.selectedIndex = val;
    }
});
```

Edit: Adding a check before updating the selectedIndex so that you can select the last n( 10 here) items as well.

Edit2: Fixing the bug pointed out by rolfv1

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks! There is a small bug though: if you select one in the last 10 items, it will end up with no selection.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that. I've fixed it now. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/3Rh4Y/1/)

Comment: I just realised that this (and my own solution as well) has a problem, it only works if you select an item below the current item, not if you go up in the list.
Furthermore, the current bug fix just stops the entire principle when you get too close to the end of the list, this can also be fixed so that the selected item is as close to the middle as possible. (Just select item 93 to see what I mean)

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that either. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/3Rh4Y/4/)'s the fixed version

Answer (score 1):

I made this small example to give you an idea how to do this, what you basically do is that you first select the item that will be at the bottom of the list when you have the desired item in the middle, so in your image, first select the item "T3", and then select the actual desired item, see this Fiddle as the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rolfv1/RZeLN/1/

```
<form name="form">
<select size=6 name="list">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
    <option value="f">f</option>
    <option value="g">g</option>
    <option value="h">h</option>
    <option value="i">i</option>
    <option value="j">j</option>
    <option value="k">k</option>
    <option value="l">l</option>
    <option value="m">m</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="choose();" value="select" />
</form>
```

and the test function in this case is just:

```
function choose(){
     document.form.list.value="k";  
     document.form.list.value="i"; 
}
```

Of course the script and everything would have to be adjusted to your needs, but it shows the idea I hope

Comment: I accepted the other answer because his was a generalized version of yours. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

So as I mentioned in my comment, I upgraded the script of tewathia a bit (so most credits go to him), so now the script works both when navigating up and down in the list, and it will always try to put the selected item as close to the center as possible:

```
$('#listF').click(function(){
    var n = 10;
    if(this.selectedIndex+n+1 > ($(this).find('option').length)){
        n=$(this).find('option').length-this.selectedIndex-1;
    }
    if(this.selectedIndex < n){
        n=this.selectedIndex;
    }
    this.selectedIndex-=n;
    this.selectedIndex+=2*n;
    this.selectedIndex-=n;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing my own fix based on both of your comments. http://jsfiddle.net/VFv4B/ This is very similar to yours. Yours is a little bit more condensed though.