# Center a Bootstrap drop-down select scroll bar to the selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Here's a question on how to [center a `<select>` scroll bar to the selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20100359).

I'd like to find a way to do the same thing for a Bootstrap Dropdown Menu so that the menu automatically scrolls to the `.active` list item.

Here's some code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown switch">
    <a href="active" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="switch-a">
      <span>Name</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu switch-items" id="switch-dd">
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li class="active active-dd"></li>
      .
      .
      .
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is this possible or do I have to a HTML `<select>` and spending time styling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only is it possible, it's actually much easier to deal with native HTML objects than it is to deal with the mysteries and inconsistencies of styling the `<select>` element.

You just have to listen to the [dropdown open event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) with `shown.bs.dropdown`.
Once it's open, just find the only `.active` item and call [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) to bring it into view.

**Like This**:

```js
$(".dropdown").on("shown.bs.dropdown", function() {
   $(this).find(".dropdown-menu li.active a").focus()
});
```

**Demo in Stack Snippets**:

```js
$(".dropdown.focus-active").on("shown.bs.dropdown", function() {
   $(this).find(".dropdown-menu li.active a").focus()
});
```

```css
.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container" >

  <div class="dropdown focus-active">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"
       data-target="#"  data-toggle="dropdown" 
       aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown trigger
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>      
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Event handler without jquery:

```
const activeOptionCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
  if (activeOptionCollection.length > 0) {
    const [activeOption] = activeOptionCollection;
    activeOption.scrollIntoView();
  }
```